# Find Google Material Icons list from a specific version

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, google-fonts, google-material-icons

I am facing an issue of missing or not showing icons in my code, example this icons doesn't show:

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="pending_actions" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example SVG icon"></mat-icon>
```

I am using angular **v10.2.7**, so I want to **know how to access the list of google material icons from this specific version.**
So I can use only available icons in my app.